# Discord Bot/Program should posts a message when a certain action takes place

Tags: c#, post, webhooks, discord

The goal: When a certain action occurs this code will execute sending an update to a discord sever the webhook is referring to. This is written in C#

The issue: The event will fire, but no message will be displayed. I have tried WebClient with StringUpload and did not find success.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    Dictionary<string, string> discordToPost = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    discordToPost.Add("content", "Hello World");

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(discordToPost);

    Uri webhook = new Uri("webhook goes here");
    client.PostAsync(webhook, content);
```

I found success when I did the exact same task in python 3. Is there a step I am forgetting in C#? Anything helps and is much appreciated.

```
import requests
import sys

discord_webhook = 'webhook goes here'
message = { "content" : "Hello World" }
requests.post( discord_webhook, data = message }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that your code is all in main and that everything you posted is what you have. That being said since you are calling an asynchronous method and not waiting for it to complete your program is terminating prior to a full post request being complete. The only difference in the two code examples you posted, python/C#, is that the requests library is not asynchronous so you will need to take that into account when dealing with the HttpClient.

To check if this is in fact the issue try changing your last line of code to:

```
var res = client.PostAsync(webhook, content).Result;
//If you want to check result value
if(res.IsSuccessStatusCode){
    Console.WriteLine("Posted message!");
}
```